# .NET Display different database variable but save as ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I don't know how to sum up what I'm trying to do in the title properly! Basically I have created a controller with EF6 and one foreign key of the Client table is MJTopicsID which links to the MJTopics table, a table of 26 topics. In the add and edit view I want the MJTopicsID to be a drop down menu displaying all the topics available however when you select it and click to add or edit an entry it adds it to the Client table as the MJTopicsID foreign key number? How do I go about this so I can apply it to all of my views.

This is the dropdown menu I created in the edit view however it just shows numbers 1-26 and if I change it to the topics variable it doesn't know it as obviously its not in the open model, thanks!

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MJTopicsID, "MJTopicsID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
  @Html.DropDownList("MJTopicsID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MJTopicsID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you have given it a list of simple prinitives such as strings or ints rather than SelectListItem. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc ?

Comment: I don't understand what's your question! Are you looking for the proper way to show the selected foreign keys or are you asking about the back-end code to link the items together?

Comment: When populating a dropdown you can set different text and value for each item in the list, so it's easy to display a text for the topics and save the corresponding numeric value. It's all about doing the right binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly then you want to display some readable value and save some db specific value like foreign key Id in this case.

In the view for helper method "DropDownList" you can give second parameter of type IEnumerable type as a list of your options  like this:

```
View:


 @Html.DropDownList("MJTopicsID", 
    (List<SelectListItem>)@ViewBag.MJTopics, 
      htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }) 



Action:


 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.MJTopics = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "Topic1", Value ="1" },
            new SelectListItem(){Text = "Topic2", Value ="2" }
        };
        return View();
    }
```

SelectListItem has two properties which you can map with your models.
Also you can use your model with "Text" as value to display and "value" as value to use.

Let "topics" is your list model for topics 
then you can write it as

```
 topics.Select(
            x=> new SelectListItem()
               {
                 Text = x.Id, 
                 value =x.Desc 
              })
```

This is the one way of doing it.

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an answer if anyone is new to EF6 and is trying to do the same thing.

In the controller for the actionresult you are trying to do this for, so in my case create it will create a viewbag variable this was mine:

```
ViewBag.MJTopicsID = new SelectList(db.MJTopicss, "ID", "ID");
```

I changed it to:

```
ViewBag.MJTopicsID = new SelectList(db.MJTopicss, "ID", "topicalTF");
```

The topicalTF is the variable for the topics available and this showed all the topics but would save it as the ID, hope this helps!